# Running jmeter on command line throwing a 400 BAD REQUEST but not on GUI

Tags: jmeter, http-status-code-400

I'm using JMeter v5.6 with Java 17 and was successful running perf test plan using GUI but when running the same test plan on the command line the http request is throwing a 400 BAD REQUEST error

Tried on JMeter versions 5.6 and 5.6.2 but error is the same.

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting [HTTP status 400](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/400) in command-line mode and the issue cannot be reproduced in GUI mode it means that you're sending different requests.

I would suggest

1. temporarily [enable saving of full JMeter request and response data](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/response-data-in-jmeter), you can add i.e. [Simple Data Writer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Simple_Data_Writer) listener and configure it to save everything:

   [image]
2. Run your test in GUI and non-GUI mode
3. Compare .jtl files from both executions and inspect failing request details using [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener
4. Amend your JMeter configuration to eliminate the difference

It also worth taking a look at [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging), if something goes wrong it normally should contain at least few lines indicating that there is an issue allowing you to guess where it could be.